# Using last date value from input file as label text in gnuplot

Tags: date, timestamp, label, gnuplot

I have some input data from a file looking like this:

```
06.03.2020  62,30
09.03.2020  60,16
10.03.2020  59,94
11.03.2020  59,34
12.03.2020  56,58
13.03.2020  56,37
```

I am able to plot the data how I want to, but as the input data and the resulting graph will be updated automatically I would like to display the up-to-date status of the graph and input data by printing the last value of column 1 as a label in the graph.

So far I have tried something like

```
set term unknown
plot [:][:] input.txt using (xlast=$1):2
set terminal qt

set label xlast at graph 0.025, graph 0.95 left
plot ...
```

but I did not manage to get an output to the graph.
Can someone please help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `strcol(1)`, I guess `$1` tries to extract a number.

**Code:**

```
### last value of column to label
reset session

$Data <<EOD
06.03.2020  62,30
09.03.2020  60,16
10.03.2020  59,94
11.03.2020  59,34
12.03.2020  56,58
13.03.2020  56,37
EOD

set table $Dummy
    plot $Data u (LastX=strcol(1)) w table
unset table

set label LastX at graph 0.025, graph 0.95 left

plot $Data u 0:(rand(0)) w l notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]